# Как узнать, кто пригласил человека в группу телеграм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telethon

Подскажите, как узнать кто пригласил в группу пользователя и сколько пригласил по количеству.
Желательно на библиотеке Aiogram или Telethon.

Весь код.

```py
import aiogram
import logging
from aiogram.types import User
from aiogram.types import ChatInviteLink
from aiogram.types import ChatJoinRequest
from aiogram.types import base
from aiogram.types import fields
from aiogram.types import Chat
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineQuery, \
    InputTextMessageContent, InlineQueryResultArticle
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext


API_TOKEN = 'moi_token'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.middleware.setup(LoggingMiddleware())

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
async def check_new_user(message: types.Message):

    invited_user = message.new_chat_members[0].full_name        # Кого пригласили в группу
    who_invited = message.from_user.full_name                   # Кто пригласил

    for user in message.new_chat_members:
        print(user.full_name)

    print(f'{invited_user=} - {who_invited=}')

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Все установленные библиотеки.

```
aiogram==2.18
aiohttp==3.8.1
aioredis==2.0.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
api-display-purposes==0.0.3
app-logger==0.1.2
APScheduler==3.6.3
async-generator==1.10
async-timeout==4.0.2
asyncpg==0.25.0
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==21.4.0
Babel==2.9.1
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2021.10.8
cffi==1.15.0
chardet==3.0.4
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
cheroot==8.6.0
CherryPy==18.6.1
clarifai==2.6.2
class-registry==2.1.2
click==8.0.3
colorama==0.4.4
configparser==3.8.1
crayons==0.4.0
cryptography==36.0.1
cursor==1.3.4
decorator==4.4.2
distlib==0.3.4
EasyProcess==1.1
emoji==1.6.3
filelock==3.4.2
filters==1.3.2
Flask==2.0.2
frozenlist==1.2.0
future==0.18.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.55.0
grpcio==1.44.0
h11==0.13.0
huepy==1.2.1
idna==2.10
imageio==2.16.1
imageio-ffmpeg==0.4.5
importlib-resources==5.4.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
instabot==0.117.0
instaloader==4.8.4
instapy==0.2.3
instapy-chromedriver==2.44
itsdangerous==2.0.1
jaraco.classes==3.2.1
jaraco.collections==3.5.1
jaraco.context==4.1.1
jaraco.functools==3.5.0
jaraco.text==3.7.0
Jinja2==3.0.3
jsonschema==2.6.0
manuel==1.10.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
MeaningCloud-python==2.0.0
mock==4.0.3
more-itertools==8.12.0
moviepy==1.0.3
multidict==5.2.0
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.22.2
outcome==1.1.0
packaging==21.3
Pillow==9.0.1
platformdirs==2.4.1
pluggy==1.0.0
plyer==2.0.0
portend==3.1.0
proglog==0.1.9
protobuf==3.19.4
py==1.11.0
pyaes==1.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.21
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.7
Pyrogram==1.4.16
PySocks==1.7.1
pyTelegramBotAPI==4.3.1
pytest==7.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-json-logger==0.1.11
python-telegram-bot==13.11
pytz==2021.3
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
PyVirtualDisplay==3.0
pywin32==303
PyYAML==6.0
regex==2021.11.10
requests==2.27.1
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
responses==0.18.0
rsa==4.8
schedule==1.1.0
selenium==4.1.2
semantic-version==2.9.0
setuptools-rust==1.1.2
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.2.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
Telethon @ https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/archive/circularimport.zip
tempora==5.0.1
TgCrypto==1.2.3
time-utility==0.2.0
timeutil==2.1.0
tl.testing==0.5
tomli==2.0.1
tornado==6.1
tqdm==4.63.0
trio==0.20.0
trio-websocket==0.9.2
typing_extensions==4.1.1
tzdata==2021.5
tzlocal==4.1
urllib3==1.26.8
utils==1.0.1
virtualenv==20.13.0
webdriver-manager==3.5.3
webdriverdownloader==1.1.0.3
Werkzeug==2.0.2
wsproto==1.1.0
yarl==1.7.2
zc.lockfile==2.0
zipp==3.7.0
```

Нашел такой код, но он для Js discord

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.guild.fetchInvites().then(guildInvites => {
    const ei = invites[member.guild.id];
    invites[member.guild.id] = guildInvites;
    const invite = guildInvites.find(i => ei.get(i.code).uses < i.uses);
    const inviter = client.users.cache.get(invite.inviter.id);
    const logChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "join-logs");
    logChannel.send(`${member.user.tag} joined using invite code ${invite.code} from ${inviter.tag}. Invite was used ${invite.uses} times since its creation.`);
  });
});
```

Как его переделать?

Пробовал вот так

```py
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def process_update(self, update: types.Update):
        """
        Process single update object

        :param update:
        :return:
        """
        types.Update.set_current(update)

        try:
            if update.message:
                types.Message.set_current(update.message)
                types.User.set_current(update.message.from_user)
                types.Chat.set_current(update.message.chat)
                return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
            if update.edited_message:
                types.Message.set_current(update.edited_message)
                types.User.set_current(update.edited_message.from_user)
                types.Chat.set_current(update.edited_message.chat)
                return await self.edited_message_handlers.notify(update.edited_message)
            if update.channel_post:
                types.Message.set_current(update.channel_post)
                types.Chat.set_current(update.channel_post.chat)
                return await self.channel_post_handlers.notify(update.channel_post)
            if update.edited_channel_post:
                types.Message.set_current(update.edited_channel_post)
                types.Chat.set_current(update.edited_channel_post.chat)
                return await self.edited_channel_post_handlers.notify(update.edited_channel_post)
            if update.inline_query:
                types.InlineQuery.set_current(update.inline_query)
                types.User.set_current(update.inline_query.from_user)
                return await self.inline_query_handlers.notify(update.inline_query)
            if update.chosen_inline_result:
                types.ChosenInlineResult.set_current(update.chosen_inline_result)
                types.User.set_current(update.chosen_inline_result.from_user)
                return await self.chosen_inline_result_handlers.notify(update.chosen_inline_result)
            if update.callback_query:
                types.CallbackQuery.set_current(update.callback_query)
                if update.callback_query.message:
                    types.Chat.set_current(update.callback_query.message.chat)
                types.User.set_current(update.callback_query.from_user)
                return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
            if update.shipping_query:
                types.ShippingQuery.set_current(update.shipping_query)
                types.User.set_current(update.shipping_query.from_user)
                return await self.shipping_query_handlers.notify(update.shipping_query)
            if update.pre_checkout_query:
                types.PreCheckoutQuery.set_current(update.pre_checkout_query)
                types.User.set_current(update.pre_checkout_query.from_user)
                return await self.pre_checkout_query_handlers.notify(update.pre_checkout_query)
            if update.poll:
                types.Poll.set_current(update.poll)
                return await self.poll_handlers.notify(update.poll)
            if update.poll_answer:
                types.PollAnswer.set_current(update.poll_answer)
                types.User.set_current(update.poll_answer.user)
                return await self.poll_answer_handlers.notify(update.poll_answer)
            if update.my_chat_member:
                types.ChatMemberUpdated.set_current(update.my_chat_member)
                types.User.set_current(update.my_chat_member.from_user)
                return await self.my_chat_member_handlers.notify(update.my_chat_member)
            if update.chat_member:
                types.ChatMemberUpdated.set_current(update.chat_member)
                types.User.set_current(update.chat_member.from_user)
                return await self.chat_member_handlers.notify(update.chat_member)
            if update.chat_join_request:
                types.ChatJoinRequest.set_current(update.chat_join_request)
                types.Chat.set_current(update.chat_join_request.chat)
                types.User.set_current(update.chat_join_request.from_user)
                return await self.chat_join_request_handlers.notify(update.chat_join_request)
        except Exception as e:
            err = await self.errors_handlers.notify(update, e)
            if err:
                return err
            raise
```

Но когда присоединяюсь в группу, в консоли пишет не мой id а id сообщения, зато id группы верно пишет.

Почитал в нете и понял, мне нужно получить update, а так же chat_join_request и еще как я понимаю inline тоже.

Вот еще, что получилось у меня найти и как то из этого, нужно слепить код, спасибо переводчику, что то перевел.

```
Chat Invite Link
Ссылка для приглашения в чат

update.chat_join_request
обновить запрос на вступление в чат

on_pre_chat_join_request
по предварительному запросу на присоединение к чату

on_post_chat_join_request
по запросу присоединиться к чату

on_post_process_chat_member
в чате после обработки

on_pre_process_chat_member
на предварительном участнике чата

on_post_process_my_chat_member
после обработки моего участника чата

on_pre_process_my_chat_member
при предварительной обработке моего участника чата


update.chat_member
обновить участника чата

self.chat_join_request_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='chat_join_request')
обработчики запросов на присоединение к чату = Handler(self, middleware key='запрос на присоединение к чату')

self.chat_member_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='chat_member')
обработчики участников чата = Handler(self, middleware_key='участник чата')

self.my_chat_member_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='my_chat_member')
self мои обработчики участников чата = Handler(self, middleware_key='мой участник чата')


self.inline_query_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='inline_query')
встроенные обработчики запросов = Handler(self, middleware_key='inline query')


self.chosen_inline_result_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='chosen_inline_result')
самостоятельно выбранные встроенные обработчики результатов = Handler(self, middleware_key='выбранный встроенный результат')

self.callback_query_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='callback_query')
самостоятельные обработчики запросов обратного вызова = Handler(self, middleware_key='callback query')

self.shipping_query_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='shipping_query')
самостоятельная доставка query_handlers = обработчик (self, middleware_key = 'запрос на доставку')

self.pre_checkout_query_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='pre_checkout_query')
самостоятельные обработчики запросов перед оформлением заказа = Handler(self, middleware_key='запрос перед оформлением заказа')

self.poll_handlers = Handler(self, middleware_key='poll')
обработчики самоопроса = Handler(self, middleware_key='poll')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
async def check_new_user(message: types.Message):

    invited_user = message.new_chat_members[0].full_name        # Кого пригласили в группу
    who_invited = message.from_user.full_name                   # Кто пригласил

    for user in message.new_chat_members:
        print(user.full_name)

    print(f'{invited_user=} - {who_invited=}')
```

invited_user  - выдает список, можно циклом пройтись по нему, если человек пригласил больше одного юзера

Comment: Вроде работает, а как пройтись циклом?
Как подключил бота, в консоле написало так:
invited_user='Название моего бота' - who_invited='Group'

Comment: Если сам вступаю в группу то пишет:
invited_user='Дмитрий' - who_invited='Дмитрий'

А если приглашаю в группу, то ничего не пишет.

Comment: Поправил код, теперь есть цикл, в котором покажет всех кого пригласили

Comment: Так же пусто, хотя бота заранее запустил, вышел с группу и пригласил и ни чего не пишет.
Только это:
INFO:aiogram:Bot: moe_nazvanie_bota [@moe_nazvanie_bota]
WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully.
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling.

Comment: не работает, не пишет, когда приглашаю в группу, подскажите как прописать, может какие то библиотеку нужно импортировать, только когда сам вступаю в группу пишет текст

Comment: скиньте код на пастбин, посмотрю

Comment: Дописал код, в вопросе, а то пастбин не хочет работать, пишет что только для чтение, даже авторизоваться не дает.

Comment: запустил у себя код который в первом окне, и у меня всё работает, даже если бот не админ в группе
Если что приглашаю в группу след. образом https://prnt.sc/LoSuVVCY_795

Comment: У бота есть все права, все галочки включены, может какая та библиотека у меня не установлена?, в вопросе опубликую список, всех библиотек.

Comment: Не работает, если приглашаю в группу, не пишет текст, а если сам вступаешь в группу то пишет текст и работает.